# Find files/folders in folder except some specific folders

Tags: bash, find

I'm trying to move all files from one folder to another, except some specific folders.

I tried this to move all files except the `.git`, `assets` or `build` folders:

`find .. ! -regex '\(.git\|assets\|build\)' | xargs mv -t ../build`

What I except this command to do:

- Find all files/folders in parent folder that are not .git, assets or build.
- Move those files/folders to ../build

The folder structure is like this:

```
.
├── application
├── assets
├── build
├── download_files
├── images
├── mybb
├── system
└── tools
```

My working directory is the tools folder.

If I execute `find .. ! -regex '\(.git\|assets\|build\)'` it still shows `.git`, `assets` and build.

What's wrong with my command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have missed some wildcard characters, try

```
find .. ! -regex '\(.*\/\.git.*\|.*\/assets.*\|.*\/build.*\)'
```

I also included the path separator (/) so that assets or build appearing as part of a path doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use bash's extended globs to filter those dirs. First make sure extglob is enabled.

```
shopt -s extglob
```

then

```
mv ../!(assets|build) ../build
```

The glob won't match files starting with `.`, so no need to filter out `.git`. However, if you want to move other files starting with `.`, then also enable the dotglob shell option.

```
shopt -s extglob dotglob
mv ../!(.git|assets|build) ../build
```